# how to configurate rabbitMQ as MQTT broker

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

I have an automate that push message every 5s in **mosquitto** broker and i want to push in **rabbitMQ**. I want to know the configuration that i should do it .

Answer (score 1):

By default the MQTT is not enabled in rabbitmq you have to enable the specific plugin:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt
```

[here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html) you can find the all documentation.